# Cleaner dynamic typescript class methods

Tags: typescript, methods

I'm converting a large project from flow to TS and am having trouble figuring out how to create dynamic class methods.  I threw together a simple working example of what I'm trying to do:

[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```js
declare type logMethod = (msg: string) => void;

class Logger {
  constructor(methods: string[]) {
    methods.forEach(method => this[method] = (msg: string) => Logger.logMethod.call(this, method, msg))
  }

  static logMethod(method: string, msg: string) {}

  [key: string]: any;
}

function LoggerFactory<T extends string>(methods: T[]): Logger & Record<T, logMethod> {
  const logger = new Logger(methods);
  return logger as Logger & Record<T, logMethod>;
}

const logger = LoggerFactory(['info', 'warn', 'error']);
logger.info('info');
logger.warn('warn');
logger.error('error');
```

this works just fine, as in `info`, `warn`, `error`, or any other method names I pass into the factory are typed properly.  However I hate having extra JS just to make the type system happy.  The `LoggerFactory` is completely unnecessary in JS and I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of it.

I was trying to go down a road like this:

```js
class Logger<T extends string[]> {
  [method in keyof T]: logMethod;
}
```

but that mapping syntax doesn't work on classes or interfaces, only normal types.  Just looking for ideas here!

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn48oW) or [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkj81m) seem like an improvement?  There really isn't any way to do this without altering the JS... unless you just do the JS completely separately and just make a [separate TS declaration file](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8x3N) for it.  Let me know if you want any or all of that as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz - woah, you did in 10 minutes what I've been banging my head against the wall for hours about.  I didn't know about that `new` type syntax!  With one minor tweak ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5xZW)), your first example is perfect!  Though i realize it wasn't a requirement in my example, there are some other normal methods on the class.  Also, I'm happy to add `x=_x` as normal JS!!  I just didn't want entirely new functions, etc.  If you want to answer I'll gladly accept, thanks!!!

Comment: Okay, answered.  You may want to add the `foo()` bit to your example code, to motivate the intersection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript requires that all `class` or `interface` types have statically-known keys.  So there's no way to annotate `class Logger<K extends string> {}` so that it has keys of type `K`.  You can definitely describe the type of a class constructor which creates instances with dynamic keys, but you won't be able to apply such a type to something declared as a `class` statement.

What you *can* do is rename your class out of the way as `class _Logger {...}`, giving it the closest type you can to your desired behavior.  Then you can write `var Logger = _Logger as LoggerConstructor` to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it's of the desired type `LoggerConstructor`, which you'll define so that its instances have dynamic keys as you want.

Here's one way to do it:

```
class _Logger {
  constructor(methods: string[]) {
    methods.forEach(method =>
      (this as Logger<any>)[method] = (msg: string) =>
        Logger.logMethod.call(this, method, msg))
  }
  foo() { return 42; }
  static logMethod(method: string, msg: string) {
    console.log("method: " + method + ", msg: " + msg)
  }
}

type Logger<K extends string> = Record<K, LogMethod> & _Logger;

interface LoggerConstructor {
  new <K extends string>(methods: K[]): Logger<K>;
  logMethod(method: string, msg: string): void;
}

var Logger = _Logger as LoggerConstructor;
```

The `_Logger` class works the way you want, but it is only known to have `foo()` as an instance method and `logMethod()` as a static method.  You'd like the a `Logger<K>` instance to act as both `Logger` and as a `Record<K, LogMethod>`, so you can define it that way (with the [intersection])(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  And finally, you can define `LoggerConstructor` as having a generic [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that produces instances of `Logger<K>` (as well as having whatever static properties you'd like to see on the constructor).

Now we can test it:

```
const logger = new Logger(['info', 'warn', 'error']);
// const logger: Logger<"info" | "warn" | "error">
logger.info('Info'); // method: info, msg: Info
logger.warn('Warn'); // method: warn, msg: Warn
logger.error('Error'); // method: error, msg: Error
console.log(logger.foo().toFixed(2)); // 42.00
logger.oops('Oops'); // error
// --> ~~~~ Property 'oops' does not exist
```

Looks good!  The compiler knows that `logger` is of type `Logger<"info" | "warn" | "error">`, and thus that `logger` has `info`, `warn`, and `error` methods.  It also knows about `foo()` from `_Logger`, and complains if you try to call a method like `oops` that doesn't exist.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gcwLIWACzgEygXigCgFsBnBALimOACcBLAOwQEpcA+KANzlswG4AofgGMANgENixKAH14CBBGpQA3vyhQhcelWoBXIcDjUiqDJmIUdDBAG0Aui1Xr1hU1mIA6AGZGAomKE0E3QsNjVndXx0WikJWEQFagAeMXoQViYbVxDMO1wCEnJKGmsWHFZwiPU5RI8RRBQcjyExEREotBiAGihssx7CpiZwgF9wnzh8RyhqVF1qeigAFgAmXigx9SoxYFohKHrkN0xgs0sSxgHSc7pGR0qNLWI4EQg6xHwAIj6sCk+oADUvWOgKgnyuRX+QMGo34Y34oEg8XkiiSAGkoBAAB7ACD0czFW4Idh4ABKEE01Ew6J6ckaZnYADIZDVFAJ+AxcdQvAFoKzqABhJ40fSGJROKD0CAAdyg6MxOLxBKsjFYp3cFDR9iYFH56NYAnUh3pWHVmBu1ghFruFC4PAE8I4YiU-PysgSiigcX5Qu0IoMRkEwmFBw9SjwUtl-PwNgA5AwfLGerHpc76EmoLHFNQjLGHAIAPQFx5+0Mo6i6sNJT4JuD-AA+YNTCwbYOzRk+FUOtVr+FjAEl6ImmOsi8CchRa1aoIOfPxu4oPM36H2AOpp2MjqBjn7mqDL6frhbzsMedvGWO+ag56ib0fF3cUc-Tq834PaF5vQ74BfUbxwSYmA8QwADFaCxCAThWIZ72WFYPAABgQk9yw8ACwGIPsAHk4Awu9t2Lc9+DHABaEj2AAPyoiioAABRzSBqFATN0OIWMoEwOAICkeg4GABUYmAIA)